# Lauch an external application using Xamarin.forms

Tags: c, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an application Xamarin.forms iOS and I want to launch an external application from my local application ,how can I do that ? Your help please !

Comment: You can use Device.OpenUri. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643604/how-can-i-natively-launch-an-external-app-from-within-xamarin-forms

Comment: this code is used to open a map but not an external application !!

Comment: You have to know the custom scheme of the external application and then use Device.OpenUri("CUSTOM_SCHEME")